# Hibernate search, filter above other filter

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to write a range query in *hibernate search* with `above` using other field? If i try using an string throws an error:

```
private BooleanJunction addInCriticalStock(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, BooleanJunction booleanJunction, boolean inCriticalStock) {
    return booleanJunction
            .must(queryBuilder
                    .range()
                    .onField("currentStock")
                    .above("minimumStock") // This is other field, also "@minimumStock"
                    .createQuery()
            );
}
```

I have been searching around the questions and hibernate docs, but all the examples are with fixed value fields, si, is this possible?

**Edit**

I am using the criteria api from what i know:

```
private FullTextQuery searchQuery(SearchRequest searchRequest, String... projection) {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
            org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

    final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager
            .getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(Product.class)
            .get();

    final BooleanJunction baseQuery = queryBuilder
            .bool();

    BooleanJunction query = addOptionalSearchTerm(queryBuilder, baseQuery, searchRequest.getSearchTerm());
    query = addOptionalProductType(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getProductType());
    query = addOptionalSupplier(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getSupplier());
    query = addOptionalYear(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getYear());
    query = addOptionalVersion(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getVersion());
    query = addOptionalModel(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getModel());
    query = addOptionalBrand(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getBrand());
    query = addOptionalInExistence(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getInExistence());
    query = addOptionalInCriticalStock(queryBuilder, query, searchRequest.getInCriticalStock());

    Query combinedQuery = query.createQuery();

    Sort sort = queryBuilder.sort()
            .byScore()
            .andByField("description")
            .createSort();

    return fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(combinedQuery, Product.class)
            .setSort(sort)
            .setProjection(projection)
            .setFirstResult((searchRequest.getPage() - 1) * searchRequest.getTop())
            .setMaxResults(searchRequest.getTop());
}
```

Comment: If you are using the criteria api there are methods like eqProperty, gtProperty etc. If you use HQL it is also possible. I have no idea how to do it with the queryBuilder though

Comment: Edited my question, i am using criteria api, but i am not able to find those methods, but know that i know that they exist, maybe the search will be easier, tomorrow i will continue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to perform is a relational query. Hibernate Search does not support such queries. It is possible to implement them by relying on lower-level APIs in Lucene, but honestly I wouldn't recommend that except, maybe, to Lucene experts: it's not easy to use, and the performance impact should be analyzed carefully.

Generally what you will do to solve that kind of problem is index an additional field, such as "minimumStockDifference", and check that it's above zero:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Product {

  private int minimumStock;
  private int currentStock;


  @Transient
  @Field
  public int getMinmumStockDifference() {
    return currentStock - minimumStock;
  }

}
```

Then your query becomes:

```
private BooleanJunction addInCriticalStock(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, BooleanJunction booleanJunction, boolean inCriticalStock) {
    return booleanJunction
            .must(queryBuilder
                    .range()
                    .onField("minimumStockDifference")
                    .above(0)
                    .createQuery()
            );
}
```

Be careful, if you have to fetch `minimumStock` from another entity, to put [`@ContainedIn` annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_associated_objects_building_a_dependency_graph_with_containedin) as appropriate, so that your `Product` entity gets reindexed whenever the `minimumStock` changes.

Note that, if you don't need full text search in the same query, you can simply not use Hibernate Search for that query and rely on Hibernate ORM queries instead, either through [HQL/JPQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql) or the [criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria).

Comment: Sure, sadly this might contain a search term where lucene capabilities are needed, however your solution seems very logical, i'll try latter and let you know, thaks a lot!